# Rename PDF in my script to include the value of the current row in Google Sheets (where the pdf was created from)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a script which splits rows in a Google Sheet, inserts the values into my tags e.g. < < Name > > into a Google Doc and then converts that doc to PDF.

All i need to know is - how do i rename the PDF's created for each row to include the value of < < Name > > in the PDF File Name?

I can set the PDF name like this - but how do i make it look at the < < Name > > value in my sheet? (New to scripting -any help would be appreciated.)

```
  // Rename the new PDF file

  var PDF_FILE_NAME = 'Name'

  if (PDF_FILE_NAME !== '') {

    newFile.setName(PDF_FILE_NAME)

  } else if (ID !== null){

    newFile.setName(ID)
  }
```

Comment: Would you like the file to be named by the name of the name of the sheets file? Or the name of the sheet on which you're working?

Comment: In my sheet, I have rows of data. One column is "Name".. The script takes each row, and inserts the values into a google doc, then converts it to pdf. I need that pdf to have the "Name" value of that row (so the person's name mentioned in that row).. does that make sense?

Comment: May I ask how you're getting the data from the sheet currently? It'd be a case of getting a value from a particular column at the row in question, I imagine

Comment: Here is a link to my sheet - my code will be there too - any help would be appreciated https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gaIRVnuryZHDbbhLdZXY4l6KL32-HUQR1Q_Ji-DAciM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to view the code; I think what you're looking for is something like `var name = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(row, column).getValue()`

Comment: I have given you access.. this doesnt work as i need it to look at the active row... The script runs through a row, creates a doc from that row - i cant specify the specific cell, it needs to be the active cell and im not sure how to do that. (im VERY new to this)

Comment: Saw your comment -but no luck. the PDF file name is still the generic name

Comment: Ah ok, may I ask what was required to fix it?

Comment: for (var columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < numberOfColumns; columnIndex++) {
        
        headerValue = headerRow[columnIndex]
        activeCell = activeRow[columnIndex]
        activeCell = formatCell(activeCell);
                
        copyBody.replaceText('<<' + headerValue + '>>', activeCell)
        
        if (headerValue === FILE_NAME_COLUMN_NAME) {
        
          ID = activeCell
          
        } else if (headerValue === EMAIL_COLUMN_NAME) {
        
          recipient = activeCell
        }
      }

Comment: awesome! Glad to hear it's working